# Scheduling tasks with a PriorityQueue

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

I'm making a `Spring` `REST` application and every time a user sends a `POST` request on a specific URL I need to send a task into a `PriortyQueue`, based on the `POST` parameters.

```
User A send a `POST` request with priority = 1
User B send a `POST` request with priority = 2
```

If a task from User A hasn't been started yet, task from User B has priority.

Does `Spring` have tools that handle this, or do I have to implement it on my own? Can someone give me some tips on how should I approach this? I need tasks to be synchronously executed.

I have found something here: [Work queues with MongoDB and Spring Integration](http://blog.zenika.com/2012/06/26/Work-queues-with-MongoDB-and-Spring-Integration/). What bothers me is that the task will be executed every 5 seconds. If tasks are not completed in 5 seconds the next time Spring will try to run tasks there will still be tasks running from a previous execution. This results in some tasks being executed twice.

Comment: I think you need to add some clarity here. Do you really mean tasks should be executed synchronously? This means the user's POST request would wait around for a response from the task on the `PriorityQueue`. Or should the POST return immediately with the task put on the queue, and your question is just around how to manage the queue?

Comment: Yes, POST should return response immediately and task goes to queue.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is [Spring Integration](http://projects.spring.io/spring-integration/) support for a [PriorityChannel](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/4.2.0.RELEASE/reference/html/messaging-channels-section.html#channel-implementations-prioritychannel).

I have worked with Spring (core and mvc) for a long time and I have never heard of such an feature in the Spring core lib, but Spring Integrations [PriorityChannel](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/4.2.0.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/integration/channel/PriorityChannel.html) looks promising.